# How to convert analytics views into GB

Tags: google-analytics-api, azure-application-insights, metrics

I would like to have an estimate or an idea in how to convert Google Analytics views into GB.
I have been looking everywhere in the Google Analytics portal but all I see is the number of views
for example

```
a day 244 views a week~ 855~ views
```

Now, Im trying to calculate price or estimate  with Application Insigths but their table of prices is on GB for example

```
$2.76 per GB per Day 

100GB per day = $220.67
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the estimated cost from Azure Monitor Costs
Azure Monitor will have two phases, first it will estimate the cost according to your data, and later it will give you the actual cost after the deployment.

- **Metrics queries and Alerts**
- **Log Analytics**
- **Application Insights**

In your case you can check Azure Application Insights [metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/standard-metrics)  pricing documentations ([MSDOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing)) and [Azure Monitor Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/monitor/)